# My console gives me an error when I put the routes to a controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm setting up a route to register an account, but my VS code gives me an error when I direct the routes to controller.js.

This is for a new website, running javascript, nodejs and react.

My routes.js:

```js
const routes = require('express').Router();

const RegisterController = require('./controllers/RegisterController');

routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Hello, World!')
});

routes.post('/register', RegisterController.store);

module.exports = routes;
```

My RegisterController.js:

```js
const User = require('../models/UserModel');

class RegisterController {
  async store(req, res) {
    const email = req.body.email.toLowerCase();
    const username = req.body.username.toLowerCase();

    const EmailExists = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    const UserExists = await User.findOne({ user: username });

    if (!EmailExists) {
      return res.json({ message: 'This email is already registered! Please, try another.' });
    };

    if (!UserExists) {
      return res.json({ message: 'This user is already registered! Please, try another.' });
    }

    const { password } = req.body.password;

    const user = await User.create({
      username,
      email,
      password
    });

    return res.json(user)

  }
}
```

I expect to register my MongoDB account.

The error VS Code gives me is:
`Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

Comment: to access non `static` methods of a class, you have to create an instance of that `class` and export it.

Answer (score 1):

`RegisterController.store` is undefined because `store` is a instance method instead of a [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) method.

```
class RegisterController {
  static async store(req, res) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a naming problem:

```
const RegisterController = require('./controllers/RegisterController');
```

if you have a class with a static function e.g.:

```
class RegisterController {
    static store(req, res) {}
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
RegisterController.store(req, res);
```

If you make the variable name the same as the class name, then how would you make a distinction between a static call and a normal call?

```
const RegisterController = require('./controllers/RegisterController');

RegisterController.store(req, res); // this is meant to be a static call

RegisterController.store(req, res); // this is meant to be a normal call
```

You create your variable name with uppercase, in my opinion it should be lowercase because else how would you make a difference between a class name and a variable name just by looking at it?

Try the following:

```
const registerController = require('./controllers/RegisterController');

routes.post('/register', registerController.store);
```

I hope this provides a solution to your problem.